# Customer Group price not add in cart page when we edit quote and quote have bundle items?

Tags: magento-1, cart, quote, bundled-product, group-price

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
 $product->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId());
 $product->save();

 $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
 $info    = $options['info_buyRequest'];
 $request = new Varien_Object();

 if (!$request->hasQty()) 
 {
      $request->setQty($item->getQty());
 }

 $request->setData($info);
 $cart->addProduct($product, $request); $cart->save();
```

If you have any idea please share here.

Thank You.

Comment: Try:

$product->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getCustomerGroupId());

Comment: Not working still. @ChiragRajput thanks for the reply.

Comment: are you iterate quote in loop? write your full code of observer

Comment: I get customer group price on my observer and one of my controller file but when we addtocart that product at that time not displayed that price.

Comment: @ChiragRajput if you have any idea then please share here.

Comment: can you please add all extention code here?

Comment: This is the only code I have nothing any extension for that.

Comment: where you are write this code?

Comment: In the cart controller

Comment: are testing with login as customer and proper customer group?

Comment: 1) Logged In with one Magento Logged In (GROUP G1)
2) We set another customer group set in cart when we addProduct in the cart. Need To Set ( GROUP G4)

Comment: $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->setGroupId([whatever your new group ID is]);
                $customer->save();

write this code before all your code.

Comment: We did it when we logged Out and logged In again at that time group reset same as before right?

Comment: can you write code i mentioned before starting of controller and test?

Comment: @ChiragRajput thanks for the reply.
Our Client Requirement  is:
1) Sales Person Logged In
2) Existing Customer Selected By Sales Person for group discount price.
so we need to set group of the Existing customer on the cart page.